# Failed chess FEN creation

Tags: javascript, p5.js, chess, fen

I'm creating a chess engine, and I've run into a problem with my FEN function. The "p" which stands for the black pawn is turned into a 24 in the `b` array. But only the first instance of "p" is recorded. I've done some amount of debugging, and I (think) it's not the `switch` function, but beyond that I'm clueless. I'm creating this with the p5.js library, but the actual FEN function is in vanilla for your convenience. Link to the web editor: https://editor.p5js.org/KoderM/sketches/jVVn2-Wxc

FEN function:

```js
function fromFen(fen) {

  const fS = fen.split(" ");

  const toMove = fS[1];
  const castleAbility = fS[2];
  const enpassant = fS[3];
  const halfMoves = fS[4];
  const fullMoves = fS[5];

  let b = [1];

  console.log("Filtered: " + fS[0].split("").filter(f => f !== "/"));

  fS[0].split("").filter(f => f !== "/").forEach(s => {

    const index = b.indexOf(1);

    console.log("S = " + s + ". Index = " + index + ".");

    if (/^\d$/.test(s)) {

      for (let i = 0; i < Number(s); i++) {

        b[index - i] = 12;

      }

      b[index + Number(s)] = 1;

    } else {

      switch (s) {

        case "p":
          b[index] = 24;
          break;
        case "n":
          b[index] = 25;
          break;
        case "b":
          b[index] = 26;
          break;
        case "r":
          b[index] = 27;
          break;
        case "k":
          b[index] = 28;
          break;
        case "q":
          b[index] = 29;
          break;
        case "P":
          b[index] = 14;
          break;
        case "N":
          b[index] = 15;
          break;
        case "B":
          b[index] = 16;
          break;
        case "R":
          b[index] = 17;
          break;
        case "K":
          b[index] = 18;
          break;
        case "Q":
          b[index] = 19;
          break;
        default:
          throw new Error("Invalid Fen: " + s);

      }

      b[index + 1] = 1;

    }

  });

  b.pop();

  let result = [];

  console.log("result: " + b + " length: " + b.length);

  while (b.length > 7) result.push(b.splice(0, 8));

  return {

    board: result,
    turn: toMove,
    castle: castleAbility,
    halfMoves: halfMoves,
    fullMoves: fullMoves

  };

}

const FENTest = fromFen("rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1");

console.log(FENTest.board);
```

For reference:

```
Rows = y (v)
Cols = x (>)

board conditions:
2: empty
3: mouseOver
4: pawn
5: knight
6: bishop
7: rook
8: queen
9: king

1: white
2: black

ex: white pawn: 14
ex: black king: 29
ex empty: 12
```

Comment: What is the expected output? "b[index - i] = 12;" this line is replacing those 24 in the array

Comment: Try changing `b[index - i] = 12` to `b[index + i] = 12`.  Otherwise it seems you're overwriting stuff you already wrote.

Comment: Oh my gosh, that actually worked. What am I thinking... If you put that in an answer I'll mark it as correct.

Comment: I assume the problem with the code is that it generates `undefined` elements.  Please confirm.

Comment: Yes, the undefined is the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in a comment, try changing `b[index - i] = 12` to `b[index + i] = 12`, as below:

```js
function fromFen(fen) {

  const fS = fen.split(" ");

  const toMove = fS[1];
  const castleAbility = fS[2];
  const enpassant = fS[3];
  const halfMoves = fS[4];
  const fullMoves = fS[5];

  let b = [1];

  console.log("Filtered: " + fS[0].split("").filter(f => f !== "/"));

  fS[0].split("").filter(f => f !== "/").forEach(s => {

    const index = b.indexOf(1);

    console.log("S = " + s + ". Index = " + index + ".");

    if (/^\d$/.test(s)) {

      for (let i = 0; i < Number(s); i++) {

        b[index + i] = 12;

      }

      b[index + Number(s)] = 1;

    } else {

      switch (s) {

        case "p":
          b[index] = 24;
          break;
        case "n":
          b[index] = 25;
          break;
        case "b":
          b[index] = 26;
          break;
        case "r":
          b[index] = 27;
          break;
        case "k":
          b[index] = 28;
          break;
        case "q":
          b[index] = 29;
          break;
        case "P":
          b[index] = 14;
          break;
        case "N":
          b[index] = 15;
          break;
        case "B":
          b[index] = 16;
          break;
        case "R":
          b[index] = 17;
          break;
        case "K":
          b[index] = 18;
          break;
        case "Q":
          b[index] = 19;
          break;
        default:
          throw new Error("Invalid Fen: " + s);

      }

      b[index + 1] = 1;

    }

  });

  b.pop();

  let result = [];

  console.log("result: " + b + " length: " + b.length);

  while (b.length > 7) result.push(b.splice(0, 8));

  return {

    board: result,
    turn: toMove,
    castle: castleAbility,
    halfMoves: halfMoves,
    fullMoves: fullMoves

  };

}

const FENTest = fromFen("rnbqkbnr/pppppppp/8/8/8/8/PPPPPPPP/RNBQKBNR w KQkq - 0 1");

console.log(FENTest.board);
```